# Water surface tension

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

I am neither a researcher nor an academic, but I do have an interest in physics as it applies to everyday life.

My current project is this: I have been commissioned to build an indoor waterfall in sheet copper of my own design. It is approximately 8' square and occupies a slightly convex wall in a medical office. The water cascades down the sheet of copper from a formed manifold and pools into a trough, in which is a re-circulation pump. It is all very beautiful and works well except for one detail: No matter what I try, droplets of water escape from the surface, apparently from the slight turbulence of the plummeting water as it descends into the trough. The droplets moisten the tile floor and become a slip hazard.

Is there a product, a surfactant or something, that I could add to the water that would change the surface tension such that the water would be less inclined to form droplets? It must not foam, and because there is understandable evaporation, there should be very little to no odor in the additive. 
I have tried an automotive product called Water Wetter, but it has a disagreeable odor when used in this application.

I apologize if I have blundered into the wrong place to ask this question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did the water wetter work, except for the odor?

Comment: It was an improvement; almost complete. However, the odor, propelled by the HVAC system, quickly curtailed my testing. Since writing the original question, I have been wondering how a dose of tri-sodium phosphate would work on the drop problem.

Comment: Why not find something that has about the same surface tension ans the wetter work solutions, but doesn't stink?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. Are you speaking of **splashing** when the waterfall plummets into and makes contact with the trough?

Comment: Great question! I wish I had an answer.

Comment: Deep, There was a splashing problem when the water got to the trough, but I solved that by installing fiber mesh screen in the trough, above the surface of the water. This prevented "bounce" of the water when it hit the surface. The remaining problem seems to be separation of the sheet of water as it travels down the copper.

Comment: If I understand it right, you have a copper sheet, and you want the water to flow over that sheet's surface, sticking to it, but instead it separates.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of anything you can do to the water that wouldn't pose other problems. What you may do is add other controls to mediate the effect of water droplets escaping. You could add an air extraction system to pull air across the feature to reduce the amount of water that hits the floor. Alternatively you could add a feature to the floor to prevent the hazard.

Even if you were to add extra troughs that reduced the falling distance and speed of the water you would still get some water escaping and potentially getting on the floor.

Drew K